# SQL statement to conditionally select related records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with fields `id` (primary key) and `fid`.  I want to get the record where `id` matches a particular value, as well as all related records that have its same `fid` value.

I can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE fid = (SELECT TOP 1 fid FROM mytable WHERE id = 'somevalue')
```

But I don't want the related records if the `fid` is a particular value (in my case an empty guid value).

Is there a way to do this in a single SQL statement?  I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

**UPDATE:**

Looking at the answers so far I think I may not have asked my question clearly.  `id` and `fid` will never be equal.  `LEFT JOIN` may be what I need, but I'm a bit SQL ignorant.  What I'm hoping for is the following two queries as a single statement:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = 'somevalue' 

SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE fid = 
    (SELECT TOP 1 fid FROM mytable 
     WHERE id = 'somevalue' AND fid != '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
```

Comment: wouldn't a join be what you are after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your revision, the problem seems to be "select all rows where `id` has a certain value and all other rows with the `id` matches "somevalue" and the `fid` is not null.

The following captures this logic:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM mytable t left outer join
     (SELECT TOP 1 fid
      FROM mytable 
      WHERE id = 'somevalue' AND fid <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
     ) t1
     on t.fid = t1.fid
WHERE id = 'somevalue' or t1.fid is not null;
```

Because `id` is a primary key, the `t1` subquery will return 0 or 1 rows.  When it returns 0 rows, you will only get the original row matching `'somevalue'`.

Comment: Yes, that works!  The answer by @BWS almost gets me what is needed too, if the OR clause uses `fid =` and also checks that the fid doesn't equal the zero guid value.  Would this approach be more/less efficient than what you propose?

Comment: @jltrem . . . Without looking at the execution plans or doing timing tests, I would think the two methods would have very similar performance.  If you have really large tables and performance is an issue, then the best query might look different.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain I understand your question, but I'll take a stab at it.  What I think you're asking is if you can select all records from one table where either the id or fid fields equal a particular value, but you don't want the related fields if the particular value you're searching on equals an empty guid value.  If so, here's how you can do it:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    mytable t1
LEFT JOIN
    mytable t2 ON (t1.id = t2.fid) AND (t2.fid IS NOT NULL);
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: gstroup's response reminded me that your fid field may not contain a null value and instead the guid may be all zeros; if so, the above join would change slightly to:  SELECT * FROM mytable t1 LEFT JOIN mytable t2 ON (t1.id = t2.fid) AND (t2.fid <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000');

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable a
JOIN mytable b ON a.id = b.fid
WHERE a.id = 'somevalue';
```

This should return all records in a (joined with all records in b where a.id = b.fid) then filtered to show only records that have a.id = 'somevalue';

Answer (score 0):

You could just add another clause to your sql statement like this:

```
SELECT * From mutable
WHERE fid = (SELECT TOP 1 fid FROM mytable WHERE id = 'somevalue' 
AND fid != '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
```

If you want more than one row, try a join as suggested by @zigdawgydawg.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are after:

```
select * from mytable
where id = 'somevalue' 
or id = (select fid from mytable where id = 'somevalue')
```

Comment: This would give me the correct result if the OR clause used `fid =` and also ensured the fid didn't equal the zero guid value.

Answer (score 0):

Almost like zigdawgydawg's contribution, but slightly different:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE fid IN 
(SELECT fid FROM mytable WHERE id = 'somevalue' )
AND NOT guid is null;
```